# Git-flow хотфиксы во время спринта

Tags: git, git-flow

Есть основные ветки dev, master.
В дев ветке ведутся работы по текущему релизу.
В средине спринта приходит реквест свыше на реализацию фичи, фича будет(должна быть) выпущена раньше текущего релиза. 
Что должно быть дальше? Новая бранча от мастера в которой будет реализация новой фичи, после чего мастер мерджим в дев? Где бы можно было бы почитать про правильные подходы для таких случаев?

Просто то, что сейчас творится на проекте это треш.
Работа с девом остановилась, дев откатываем до состояния мастера, разрабатываем фичу в дев (у которого по сути состояние мастера), накатываем прежнее состояние дева.

Comment: В гитфлоу есть же хотфиксы. С точки зрения флоу такое требование сверху это тоже хотфикс

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте вопросу нормальное название. То что вопрос про гитфлоу видно и так, по меткам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, вряд ли в подобной ситуации найдется "канонично" верный ответ. Причиной тому является то, что если вы работаете по agile спринтам, то добавление крупного функционала посреди спринта не является адекватной практикой. Так, что фактически описанный вами git-flow не совместим с подобным стилем разработки (когда неожиданно прилетает задание).

Предположу, что функционал, который у вас находится сейчас в dev вам в любом случае еще понадобится, по этому выбрасывать его не вариант. В связи с этим предложил бы следующее решение:

1. Временно оставить dev в покое.
2. От master сделать отдельную ветку под фичу, в которой будет вестись разработка.
3. Довести разработку в ветке до конца, влить в master после приемки/тестирования/релиза/апрува.
4. Подлить в dev изменения из master и продолжить работу в dev

Если, подобные ситуация с вклиниванием блока задач или огромной фичи для вас являются нормальной практикой, то я бы предложил вам немного пересмотреть git-flow в сторону следующего подхода:

1. После релиза от master ветки создается (или актуализируется dev).
2. Для каждой крупной фичи или сгруппированного по смыслу блока задач делается отдельная ветка от dev.
3. В каждой такой отдельном ветке ведется разработка фичи (или блока задач) параллельно до момента готовности.
4. Когда фича (или блок задач) в ветке проходит приемку/тестирование ветка подливается в dev.
5. Когда все тематические ветки из спринта прошли приемку/тестирование отладку, эти ветки сливаются в dev и происходит приемочное тестирование.
6. После успешного прохождения приемки в master подливается dev и происходит релиз.
7. Переходим к шагу 2

Такой git-flow будет более гибким и позволит вам вклинивать такие внезапные задачи "сверху" без катастрофических последствий в репозитории. Тематические ветки всегда есть возможность обновить с dev (если туда сольются какие-то другие фичи) - актуализировать.

Answer (score 2):

Не встречал еще на практике адекватного использование git-flow.

Либо в dev треш, и ветки мержатся сразу в master, а затем в dev для вида.

Либо вся работа ведется в dev, и мержится в master для вида. Во втором случае dev и master совпадают по содержимому.

Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант отказа от git-flow, во всяком случае от ветки dev. Проще и понятнее создавать рабочие и релизные ветки из master.

А ответ на поставленный вопрос - хотфикс.